# /etc/hosts blocks instead of redirecting

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, localhost, hosts-file

I'm trying to redirect Facebook to localhost on Mac OS Ventura.

This is my /etc/hosts

```
hello procrastinator...%                                                                                                                ➜  Documents cat /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
fe80::1%lo0             localhost


127.0.0.1 www.hotnews.ro
fe80::1%lo0 www.hotnews.ro

127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1 static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 static.ak.connect.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1 www.connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1 meta.com
127.0.0.1 www.meta.com

# Block Facebook IPv6
fe80::1%lo0 facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0 login.facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0 www.login.facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0 fbcdn.net
fe80::1%lo0 www.fbcdn.net
fe80::1%lo0 fbcdn.com
fe80::1%lo0 www.fbcdn.com
fe80::1%lo0 static.ak.fbcdn.net
fe80::1%lo0 static.ak.connect.facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0 connect.facebook.net
fe80::1%lo0 www.connect.facebook.net
fe80::1%lo0 apps.facebook.com
```

Also, I started httpd on my machine, such that it serves a 'hello procrastinator' page on 127.0.0.1:

[image: hello procrastinator page]

However, when i go to Facebook I am not being redirected, I'm just being blocked, and this is what I see:

[image]

Does anybody have any advice on what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does your local webserver have a certificate to support HTTPS?

Comment: No, it does not. Do you think that this would make a difference?

Comment: Take away the s in `https://` so it is `http://` if that fixes it then yes you will need to set up your http server to send secure http pages: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/webserver-use-https

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, now I've got another problem :( After I deploy SSL on localhost, the browsers refuses to connect with the following error: `Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from facebook.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Subject: mkcert development certificate

Issuer: mkcert mircea@Mirceas-MacBook-Pro-2.local

Expires on: 12 Nov 2025

` I guess it's because my certificate is for localhost? Would it help if I created the cert for facebook.com?

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it answers my question. But if you had any idea on how to solve the above issue, maybe we could edit together my question and your answer to also include this?

Comment: It is most likely due to the domain name mismatch, as you say your certificate is for localhost while you are calling up `facebook.com`. You may be able to to set up sub-sites https://geekflare.com/multiple-domains-on-one-server-with-apache-nginx/ with certificates for each of them but I don't know the exact details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local webserver is not configured to support HTTPS,
which also needs a certificate.

As the webserver is not listening on the HTTPS port number 443,
it's logical that the browser won't be able to connect.